# CollectionView kind View, scrollable horizontally + vertically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have a very big problem with an application I am currently developing...
I wanted to achieve one kind of "timetable" behavior, so I hard-coded a View which I called TimeTableView, which porpouse was (as its name points) to show schedules and things like that.

The problem I got here was that I wasn't using any kind of Reusability Algorithm, so the application, when running huge schedules, was so slow and often crashed in memory testing it on an iPad1. (Despite of being freeing allocations and so on).

I am not an experienced programmer in objectiveC, so I wanted to know if there is any kind of Open Source Library or piece of code that actually handles reusability and things like that in a view with these characteristics.

This attached image shows an abstraction of the problem I am facing with.
Hope you can help me with this trouble!

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You could search for implementations of gridview-like components, like [THIS](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dtgridview).

Comment: Well it helped! I still have to check memory leaks and allocation faults but it goes really smooth when scrolling. Thanks Templar

Answer (score 1):

[GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView) is maybe the framework you're lookig for.

Comment: Well, I tried it and Is not really what I am looking for, the problem is I want to use it scrollable horizontally + vertically, and I didn't find until now a library that uses that kind of thing! 
Anyhow, Thanks for replying!